# Restricting SSRS subscriptions to shared schedules only

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I'm reasonably new to SQL Server Reporting Services and Report Manager, and completely new to SSRS's Subscriptions. We're running SSRS 2008.

Out of the box it seems that a user with the Browser role can create a Subscription to a report and schedule it to run at any time they choose.

As an admin I have setup a schedule called "Overnight reports" and have it run every night from 1am.

I would like it so that when a regular user creates their Subscription they can **only** use one of my shared schedules so that their subscription will only run overnight.

Is this possible?

Thanks

-Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK well I haven't been able to find an answer for this.

I am able to hide the radio button for selecting their own schedule and the "Select Schedule" button using CSS, by changing ReportingServices.css (located in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportManager\Styles on my Win 2008 server)

```
input#ui_rdoOnSchedule { display:none; }
input#ui_btn_SpecifyScheduleSubscriptionProp { display:none; }
```

However it's not very elegant - the text for "When the scheduled report run is complete" and "At 8:00 am every Mon of every week" is still visible.

-Matt